# Why does Delphi XE2 not find the QrCtrls.dcu file for the QuickReports package?

Tags: delphi, report, delphi-xe2

I have Delphi XE2 Professional, and QuickRep505 components was installed with it, but the source code is not available.

A project I am starting to maintain uses a QrCtrls.dcu file, but cannot find it when I run the project.

I have tried to configure it by going to `Tools > Configure Tools...`, clicking Add and entering:

**Name:** QuickRep505

**Program:** QR5DesignDXE2.bpl

**Working Directory:** C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\

Delphi still cannot find the file.

Comment: Please contact the component vendor, or post on their forum. You are better off asking the people that produce the software for support.

Comment: The "Configure tools" command is for configuring the *programs* that appear on the Tools menu. It has nothing to do with finding units at compile time. You've told Delphi that you want a "QuickRep505" item on the Tools menu, and when you select it, you want the IDE to attempt to execute a BPL file, the same way Windows Explorer would if you double-clicked that BPL file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, I've just tried it and it works fine for me. You are just missing the path to the sources in your environment (project) options:

- go to `Tools/Options` menu item in your Delphi IDE
- in the newly opened `Options` dialog

  - go to `Environment Options/Delphi Options/Library` tree view item
  - click on the `...` button beside the `Library path` edit box
  - in the newly opened `Directories` dialog enter the path to your `Quickrep505` directory into the edit box or browse for it using the button with the opened folder icon and after you set it
  - click on the `Add` button and confirm the dialog by clicking on the `OK` button
- finally confirm the `Options` dialog by clicking on the `OK` button
- now you should be able to build your project

Comment: Thank you very much :-) It finally compiled.